# Cognito and Ionic 3 - keep users logged in

Tags: ionic3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building an app in ionic 3 in combination with cognito and amplify. Currently, I'm trying to keep the users logged in - even if the app has been closed. Logging in goes perfectly and keeping the user logged in for while as well, but force-closing the app and the user will see the login page again.

Before the login page is shown I receive the following message in the console: [DEBUG] 41:22.567 AuthClass - get current authenticated user. source no credentials.

As far I can tell from the documentation - amplify will handle the refreshing of the session, when calling currentSession(). I can also see that the tokens are stored in the localstorage and are still present when the app is closed and reopened.

Do you guys have any clues where I need to start digging?

PS I did tell cognito to set the validity of the refresh token to 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

Question was solved. I used an older library of the Amplify library. Installing the latest version solved my problems.